# Where should I save images to have them appear in the Gallery app?

Tags: file-system, photos, gallery

Running KitKat, I want to extract a zip file with photos and place them in a folder where the Gallery app will find them. I'm using Android File Manager and Easy Unrar Lite to move files around and extract them. Where in the file systems should I put them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter where you put them. A convenient place usually is the (internal or external) SD card, where you simply could create a `Photos` folder, and extract your photos to.

The gallery app simply checks the devices media database, it doesn't check the directories directly. This database gets fed by the so-called *Media Scanner*, which gets triggered by different system events, such as immediately after a completed boot, or whenever the SD card gets mounted. This is why you don't see the extracted images immediately. See [my answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/59186/16575) for how to trigger it "on demand" (hint: for Kitkat, try the [SD Scanner](http://www.appbrain.com/app/sd-scanner/com.gmail.jerickson314.sdscanner) app).

Comment: Just to clarify what @Izzy says: it does not matter where to put them, as long as the folder where you extract the files **does not contain** a file named `.nomedia` which would hide all the pictures (songs and videos too) in that folder to the _Media Scanner_. The `.nomedia` file is hidden, so if you want to delete it you must use a file explorer app which allows to see hidden files (I use _ES File Explorer_)

Comment: This is a great resource for media (re)scanner apps. https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/mediascanner

Comment: @Gaia Agreed :) Glad you like it!